# Embedding Webview2 dll within an exe file WPF

Tags: wpf, dll, embed, webview2

I want to release my WPF app just in an .exe file. I have 3 dll's from the WebView2 nuget package.

```
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.dll
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll
```

As noted, Costura.Fody doesn't work for this, but I have a native runtime .dll and I saw this can help to release the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of .NET are you targeting? This will be easiest if you're on .NET 5+ (ideally 6).

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview) documents how to publish a .NET application as a single file, with instructions for the `dotnet` CLI and Visual Studio. I believe you will need to follow the instructions under "Including native libraries" and set the `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` MSBuild property to true, as both WPF and the WebView2 bindings use a native DLL.